# String response separated by "|" to Android JSONObject

Tags: android, arrays, split

I'm getting a HTTP GET response like this:
(yeah, I know it's weird)

```
1,24,https://www.myweb.com/img/BTMz_shave_club.png|10,21,https://www.myweb.com/img/BTMz_coffee_club.png|30,22,https://www.myweb.com/img/BTMz_coffee_club.png|
```

I need to split the String by "|". And then split "," and result is something like:

```
[
  {id: 1, qty: 24, img_uri: https://www.myweb.com/img/BTMz_shave_club.png},
  {id: 10, qty: 21, img_uri: https://www.myweb.com/img/BTMz_coffee_club.png},
  {id: 22, qty: 22, img_uri: https://www.myweb.com/img/BTMz_coffee_club.png}
]
```

It's a String response, but I need to convert it to an JSONArray.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ikram Hussain answer works perfect.

Comment: The function result is:

`[{"id":"1","qty":"24","img_uri":"https:\/\/www.myweb.com\/img\/BTMz_shave_club.png"},{"id":"10","qty":"21","img_uri":"https:\/\/www.myweb.com\/img\/BTMz_coffee_club.png"},{"id":"30","qty":"22","img_uri":"https:\/\/www.myweb.com\/img\/BTMz_coffee_club.png"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like

```
private void splitAndMakeJson() {


    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    String mainString="1,24,https://www.myweb.com/img/BTMz_shave_club.png|10,21,https://www.myweb.com/img/BTMz_coffee_club.png|30,22,https://www.myweb.com/img/BTMz_coffee_club.png|";

    String[] mainToken=mainString.split("\\|");

    for(int i=0;i<mainToken.length;i++){
        String subToken[]=mainToken[i].split(",");
        jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("id",subToken[0].getBytes().toString());
            jsonObject.put("qty",subToken[1].getBytes().toString());
            jsonObject.put("img_uri",subToken[2].getBytes().toString());
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    Log.e("Json",jsonArray.toString());
}
```

Comment: `getBytes().toString()` is not needed

Comment: Thanks a lot Ikram Hussain you code works like a charm. How cricket_007 says: getBytes().toString() is not needed.

Thanks you guys.